# Keep getting error: implode(): Invalid arguments passed when updating data

Tags: php, laravel, implode

I keep on getting this error whenever I try to update something into my data. It didn't happen a lot the last time but after putting the new update function, the error keep popping out and for some reason it points back to the new function that I had entered even though I am updating at the old function.

Controller:

```
//update for user
    public function edit($id){
        $object = user::find($id);

        return view('edit', compact('object'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $object = user::find($id);
        $object->Name = $request->input('Name');
        $object->update();

        return redirect('/home');
    }


    //update for Schools table
    public function edit1($id){
      $object2 = school::find($id);
       return view('edit1', compact('object2'));

    }
    public function update1(Request $request, $id){
        $object2 = school::find($id);
        $test = array();
    $test['School'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);
    $test['SDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->SDate);
    $test['EDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->EDate);
        $object2->update($test);
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    //error start here after putting this whole thing in. (I tried putting it into another separate controller but the error still continues)
            public function edit2($id){
      $object3 = hobby::find($id);
       return view('edit2', compact('object3'));

    }
    public function update2(Request $request, $id){
        $object3 = hobby::find($id);
    $test2 = array();
    $test2['computer_game'] = implode(' , ', $request->computer_game);
    $test2['reading_book'] = implode(' , ', $request->reading_book);
        $object3->update($test2);
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Error is highlighting this part even though when I try to update user or school data

```
$test2['computer_game'] = implode(' , ', $request->computer_game);
```

And it says

> :implode(): Invalid arguments passed

I have no issue updating the hobby data but it the error keep pointing it back to the hobby implode part.

Is it possible I could only use update once on an implode function? Thanks in advance

edit2.blade.php (edit page for hobby, as shown it is an array)

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object3->id) }}">
              {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
              {{ csrf_field() }}
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
              <tr >
                            <th class="text-center">
                  #
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                  Sports:
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                  Books read:
                </th>
                              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id='addr0'>
                <td>
                1
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name='computer_game[]' class="form-control"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name='reading_book[]' class="form-control"/>
                </td>
                              </tr>
                        <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($request->computer_game)` yield?

Comment: Can you please show us the returned value of `var_dump($request->computer_game)` ??

Comment: @Maraboc It does nothing

Comment: Check dd($request->computer_game);` !!

Comment: It return me this  array:1 [▼ 0 => "LOL" ]

Comment: @blastme Try my solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP implode(): Invalid arguments passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601881/php-implode-invalid-arguments-passed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just simple try the following:

```
$test2['computer_game'] = implode(' , ', (array)$request->computer_game);
```

This will convert `$request->computer_game` in to an array if it is not already.

Comment: tks for the reply, I tried your solution and it didn't get any error but it didn't update until my data

Comment: yup it return the value that I had entered but didn't update it

Comment: Erm ok.. What question do I ask? Sorry I still don't know what problem have you found out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845815/model-not-updating-laravel @mega6382 I have posted the question please take a look, I also changed the controller abit

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because $request->computer_game is not an array. This can be verified by dumping the variable and killing the script.

```
var_dump($request->computer_game); die;
```

Comment: tks for the quick reply, I tried your code there weren't any error but there was no update being done and actually the computer_game is an array, I shall update my question to show you the edit page

Answer (score 0):

first of all what does var_dump(); gives to that object oriented array. plz share then we'll try to answer.

Then to stop multiple loading you can make a private var ($loaded) and by default it would be false`private static $loaded = false;`  then befor any code starts in function use if statement to detect if loaded is true

```
if(self::$loaded){
    return;
}
self::$loaded = true
```

this would help you! please post var_dump!

Comment: the variable declairation should be at top of class. before any code.

Comment: So your var_dump doesn't give anything; The array is empty maybe. The other thing you should notice in the edit2 that is do not use {{}} because it compiles only the variables not functions