# Model not updating laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

I can't seem to update my user and school table anymore but was able to update hobby table now.

[Keep getting error: implode(): Invalid arguments passed when updating data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845065/keep-getting-error-implode-invalid-arguments-passed-when-updating-data/46845303?noredirect=1#comment80638799_46845303) --> linking back to the question before

Controller:

```
        //update for user
        public function edit($id){
            $object = user::find($id);

            return view('edit', compact('object'));

        }

        public function update(Request $request, $id){
            $object       = user::find($id);
            $object->Name = $request->input('Name');

            $object->update();

            return redirect('/home');
        }

        //update for Schools table
        public function edit1($id){
           $object2 = school::find($id);

           return view('edit1', compact('object2'));
        }

        public function update1(Request $request, $id){
            $object2 = school::find($id);

            $test           = array();
            $test['School'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);
            $test['SDate']  = implode(' , ', $request->SDate);
            $test['EDate']  = implode(' , ', $request->EDate);

            $object2->update($test);
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        // The error starts here after putting this whole thing in.
        // (I tried putting it into another separate controller but the error
        // still continues)
        public function edit2($id) {
           $object3 = hobby::find($id);

           return view('edit2', compact('object3'));
        }

        public function update2(Request $request, $id){
            $object3 = hobby::find($id);

            $test2                  = array();
            $reading_book           = (array)$request->reading_book;
            $test2['reading_book']  = implode(' , ',$reading_book );
            $computer_game          = (array)$request->computer_game;
            $test2['computer_game'] = implode(' , ',$computer_game );

            $object3->update($test2);

            return redirect('/home');
        }
```

Hobby model:

```
   <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Eloquent;

    class hobby extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $fillable = array('reading_book','computer_game','user_id');

        public function users() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\user, 'user_id', 'id');
        }
    }
```

Route: (currently using these for updating)

```
Route::get('/user/show/{id}/edit', 'HomeController@edit');
Route::put('/user/show/{id}','HomeController@update');


Route::get('/user/show/{id}/edit1', 'HomeController@edit1');
Route::put('/user/show/{id}','HomeController@update1');


Route::get('/user/show/{id}/edit2', 'HomeController@edit2');
Route::put('/user/show/{id}','HomeController@update2');
```

Comment: Can you show us the route you're using?

Comment: Is there any errors ??

Comment: Did you get the answer in your previous question? [Keep getting error: implode(): Invalid arguments passed when updating data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845065/keep-getting-error-implode-invalid-arguments-passed-when-updating-data/46845303?noredirect=1#comment80638799_46845303)

Comment: @maraboc There is no error but I can't seem to update any data

Comment: @ljubadr The answer had helped me abit but one of them told me to create another question as it is too messy there

Comment: can you provide the error? check `storage/logs/laravel.log` file

Comment: @ljubadr there is no error at all, it just return the way I want but not updating any of my data

Comment: in `update2()` method, can you add the `dd($request->all());` and post that here?

Comment: I had did that already all the data can be seen and their all in array

Comment: it's about what's the data itself, not if it's there. We can just guess what data did you sent from your view. Every bit helps to track down the bug

Comment: I got this "array:4 [▼ 
"_method" => "PUT" 
"_token" => "SoOsHkbd7fnih9XKskgq8SSgZ8yMnqmxqPlhWL3N" 
"computer_game" => array:1 [▼ 
0 => "LOL" 
] 
"reading_book" => array:1 [▼ 
0 => "something" 
] 
]
"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your routes :

```
Route::put('/user/show/{id}','HomeController@update');

Route::put('/user/show/{id}','HomeController@update1');

Route::put('/user/show/{id}','HomeController@update2');
```

It's the same route for three methods.

Just for testing you can do that :

```
Route::put('/user/show/{id}','HomeController@update');

Route::put('/user/showupdate1/{id}','HomeController@update1');

Route::put('/user/showupdate2/{id}','HomeController@update2');
```

And change in the view this will work perfectly :)

Comment: But I put it all in different method, so shouldn't it still work? because the first 2 update and update2 works just now. Hold on let me try

Comment: @blastme How can it know what route you want to access if you call it all in the same way?

Comment: It will be a random behavior i think

Comment: It will trigger only the last one that overwrites the others

Comment: Hi, I had tried your method already but the same result, I could only update hobby but not the rest of the data. There is no error being shown

Comment: @Maraboc I tried your method again but for some reason my page cannot be found. I check the view page "  <a href="{{ url('/user/showupdate1/'.$object2->id.'/edit1') }}">Edit</a>" and I have changed it and I also already changed it inside the edit page " <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/showupdate1/'.$object2->id) }}">"

Comment: because you shoud update even this route in your case `Route::get('/user/show/{id}/edit1', 'HomeController@edit1');` to `Route::get('/user/showupdate1/{id}/edit1', 'HomeController@edit1');` or in the view do this `<a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object2->id.'/edit1') }}">Edit</a>` without changing the route !

Comment: Oh ya, your right I forgotten about that *facepalm* Thank you so much for your help !!!

Comment: Happy to help ;)